# Screen not fully updated before function is left

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem that is in some ways more of a curiosity than an error although something I'd dearly like to fix.

I have a panel in a C# Winform that has graphical representations of approximately 100 devices represented by buttons with bitmaps on them.

On starting up, the software scans an RS485 bus and creates these devices on screen.

Unfortunately, what I have noticed is that towards the end of the scan function the devices stop appearing so quickly and then there seems to be a stutter, and they all appear.

My hunch with this is that the scanning function has finished, has returned to its caller which has gone to another function which is now taking up CPU time taking resource away from the UI thread.

Just wondering if anyone has got any ideas how I can prevent the software returning from the scanning function before the screen has been fully updated.

Any thoughts/tips very greatly received.

Thankyou,

David

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like during your scan you create the buttons as you find them. Instead, do your scan, store the data , and once the scan is completely over, *then* start drawing buttons.

Ideally, do your scan in a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) thread and store the RS485 devices you find in some type of list like `List<IRS485Device>` all the while firing off [ProgressChanged events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) to update a progress indicator on your panel. When [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) has been reached you can remove your progress indicator from your panel and then call your routine that draws the buttons from all the data you've discovered in your scan.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your answer - unfortunately I'm already doing most of what you have suggested - the actual input into the bit of code that draws the devices is a list<> which is produced from a background worker, but I may well look at using a progress indicator on the panel to get around it - trouble is that it does look really cool having the devices pop up on screen as they are found!